# Phpstorm при переключении ветки не подтягивает изменения в файлах из git

Tags: git, phpstorm

Файлы находятся на сервере, настроен деплоймент туда же, а также рабочий каталог git - там же.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

1. файл `index.php` поменял свое содержимое в master ветке на сервере после `git pull origin master`
2. отбранчевался в консоли (не PHPStorm!) на сервере на новую ветку `test-branch`
3. открыл PHPStorm, который увидел, что я переключился на новую ветку, что показал внизу в статус баре
4. однако, содержимое файла `index.php` не соответствует тому, что находится на сервере куда деплоится, и который также находится под гитом, и при сохранении "пропадают" изменения, загруженные в пункте 1

Какое-то странное для меня поведение. Почему PHPStorm не посмотрел по гиту изменения и не предложил их мне выкачать из репо либо с рабочего каталога? Приходился регулярно делать "Скачать с удаленного сервера" для всего проекта, а это накладно. А если забудешь - в файле `index.php` окажутся устаревшие данные. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Возможно поможет поставить в настройках Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> Explicitly check for incoming commits on remotes на Always

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис Спасибо, поставил, понаблюдаю

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, ваш совет не помог, файл на сервере и в PHPStorm расходятся